# web service request log

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have created a web service in c# using framework 3.5 it works fine when requested by Soap UI but does not work with client Tool which they are using. So, what I want is how can I log the request xml coming from client at IIS level. so, that I can check whether the client request is hitting my service or not and can log the request.
How can I achieve this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write log in your webservice methods. But if this is not possible due to any reason. You can configure and use the logging to identify if request is reaching IIS.

[image]

You can read more in IIS [Logging Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525410(v=vs.90).aspx) and [Configure Logging in IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis)

Comment: I have already written logs in my web service methods and it works perfectly with Soap UI, but the point is when client uses he is getting 500 error code so for that i want to check the request format xml and log that on IIS whether it is hitting my service or not. And also IIS logging it too didn't worked.

Comment: The 500 error usually has more details like check for 500.19, 500.21 etc. This will narrow down the scope to find reason behind the error.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,but I tried different way and was able to track the client request using Gloab.asax file using Application_BeginRequest event.